# IndexError: tuple index out of range when creating a session-based recommender

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to create a session based recommender when i run this block of code i get this error

```
%%time

start_time_window_index = 1
final_time_window_index = 4

for time_index in range(start_time_window_index, final_time_window_index):
    # Set data
    time_index_train = time_index
    time_index_eval = time_index + 1
    train_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, f"{time_index_train}/train.parquet"))
    eval_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, f"{time_index_eval}/valid.parquet"))

    # Initialize dataloaders
    trainer.train_dataloader = get_dataloader(train_paths, train_args.per_device_train_batch_size)
    trainer.eval_dataloader = get_dataloader(eval_paths, train_args.per_device_eval_batch_size)

    # Train on day related to time_index
    print('*'*20)
    print("Launch training for day %s are:" % time_index)
    print('*'*20 + '\n')
    trainer.reset_lr_scheduler()
    trainer.train()
    trainer.state.global_step += 1

    # Evaluate on the following day
    train_metrics = trainer.evaluate(metric_key_prefix='eval')
    print('*'*20)
    print("Eval results for day %s are:\t" % time_index_eval)
    print('\n' + '*'*20 + '\n')
    for key in sorted(train_metrics.keys()):
        print(" %s = %s" % (key, str(train_metrics[key])))
    wipe_memory()
```

the error

```
********************
Launch training for day 1 are:
********************

[3/3 00:00, Epoch 3/3]
Step    Training Loss

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<timed exec> in <module>

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in evaluate(self, eval_dataset, ignore_keys, metric_key_prefix)
   2932 
   2933         eval_loop = self.prediction_loop if self.args.use_legacy_prediction_loop else self.evaluation_loop
-> 2934         output = eval_loop(
   2935             eval_dataloader,
   2936             description="Evaluation",

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers4rec/torch/ranking_metric.py in _metric(self, ks, scores, labels)
    135         rel_count = num_relevant[rel_indices]
    136 
--> 137         if rel_indices.shape[0] > 0:
    138             for index, k in enumerate(ks):
    139                 rel_labels = topk_labels[rel_indices, : int(k)]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I checked everything everything looks and runs well until this part